# Making Ipad only app to universal without resubmitting

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have submitted my app for iPad only on app store. Is it possible to revert it to universal allowing to downloads on iPad as well as iPhone without resubmitting.

I did some googling but couldn't find anything useful.

FYI: It an app created using meteorJs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to submit an update to your app in the App Store as the app type is embedded in the file you submit.

Apple will need to review your changes (i.e. Validate that it works correctly on iPhone).

Comment: actually what we have done with our app is that it detects the device and if its an phone it displays a splash screen

Comment: I see there is no way without resubmitting an update.....So when i resubmit i do it as Universal

Comment: if you need to change anything in the compiled bundle (device type in info.plist, code etc) then you need to,resubmit